# In Powershell How do I silence inlinescript messages from cmdlet

Tags: powershell, workflow

I have  a script that uses workflow and inline scripts.

Here is an example

```
workflow PingExample ($computerNames) {
   foreach -parallel ($computerNames in $y)
   inlinescript { $PingM = New-Object System.Net.NetworkInformation.Ping
                $pingObj = $PingM.Send($using:comp)}
   return $pingObj
   }
```

The problem is that PowerShell cmdlet is flashing up messages like: -

```
Inlinescript
       Running
1.6.5   PingExample : Line 1 char 6
```

As there are parallel processes running the messages constantly strobing on the screen.

How can I silence these messages?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the example you gave, there's a return. When running code like that directly in powershell, it's expected that the return will show up in the pipeline. You could simply remove the return or you could looping the command through something like invoke-command. My guess is that you're probably trying to capture those returns. Maybe assigning a variable before the workflow could work? That way, you can inspect the returns in the variable?